# Redirect rewritten URL to a new rewritten URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on my website link architecture. I would like to redirect with my .htaccess already rewritten URL to a new one to keep my incoming links active.

*www.website.com/profile-info/* to *www.website.com/profile/*

This is my actual working .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /profile-info/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . models.php [L]
```

So in order to redirect */profile-info/* to the new URL : */profile/* . I end up with this code. However it redirects */profile/* to */profile-info/*.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /profile/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /profile-info/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Please state in an explicit manner what the incoming request is and what final target should be called internally.

Comment: Sorry, but those "to" statements are ambiguous, different people look at the term "rewrite" from different sides. So once more: what is the incoming request, what is the internal target?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what do you mean by incoming request ? Until now website.com/models.php is rewritten to be website.com/profile-info, but now I want website.com/profile-info to be redirected to website.com/profile.

Comment: The incoming request is what the browser sends. The confusion raises because it is unclear if you want to rewrite the URL or the request, which would result in opposite directions / results.

Comment: You are right. I want all my incoming links from website.com/profile-info redirected to website.com/profile. Which is the same page server side (**models.php**). Please tell me how can I be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap /
RewriteRule ^/?profile-info/?$ /profile [END,NE,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?profile/?$ models.php [L,QSA]
```

It is a two step strategy:

1. redirect "old" links pointing to `/profile-info` to the new `/profile`
2. internally rewrite `/profile` to `models.php`

You may have to change the `RewriteMap`, this obviously depends on your situation.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server, often without reason. They are only provided for situation where you do *not* have access to the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers) or in case an application needs to write its own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare...).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really see a connection to the issue above. What change to what other URLs and what does "doesn't seem to work" mean? I suggest you post a separate question for that...

Answer (score 1):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect /profile-info to /profile
RewriteRule ^profile-info/?$ /profile [R=301,NE,L]

# rewrite /profile to /models.php
RewriteRule ^/?profile/?$ models.php [L,NC]
```